# Declaration works when compiling but not when running mocha tests

Tags: typescript

I have a simple declaration file that declares a module and puts a single class in that module:

```
declare module 'somemodule' {
  export class Thing {
    constructor(config: any);
  }
}
```

The original module is an internal project that lacks its own declaration file. It looks roughly like this:

```
// index.js
module.exports = require('./src/Thing');

// src/Thing.js
class Thing {
  constructor(config) {
    // stuff
  }
}

module.exports = Thing;
```

I have a file in my project that uses the module:

```
// src/usething.ts
import { Thing } from 'somemodule';

const thing = new Thing({name:'hi'});
```

When I run `tsc -p .` everything compiles fine.

However when I try to run tests with:

```
mocha -r ts-node/register 'test/**/*-spec.ts'
```

it fails with:

```
src/usething.ts:8
const thing = new Thing({name:'hi'});
                ^
TypeError: somemodule_1.Thing is not a constructor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this directory structure:

```
src/
  node_modules/
    somemodule/
      index.js
      thing.js
      package.json
  index.ts
  somemodule.d.ts
  package.json
```

#### Declaration File

The [`module-class.d.ts`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-class-d-ts.html) template will work for you.

```
// somemodule.d.ts
declare module 'somemodule' {
    class Thing {
        constructor(config: any);
    }

    export = Thing;
}
```

It is an appropriate declaration template because your `somemodule/index.js` module exports something that can be constructed with `new` and uses a CommonJS export style. There are [more details here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/library-structures.html) on the declaration templates that are appropriate for different module/library structures.

#### Import Style

Now that you have the declaration file, you need to import the module. Here are two ways to do that.

```
// index.ts
import Thing = require('somemodule');
const thing = new Thing({ name: 'hi' });
```

This second example requires your `tsconfig.json` file to have `"esModuleInterop": true`.

```
// index.ts
import Thing from 'somemodule';
const thing = new Thing({ name: 'hi' });
```

Comment: The problem I'm having with this is that the module i'm pulling in comes from package.json and lives in node modules. If I follow this more or less exactly, it doesn't seem to make the connection between somemodule and the import. (Cannot find module 'somemodule'.)

Comment: I updated the answer to target `node_modules/somemodel/`.